# npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve npm ERR! While resolving: @nestjs/mongoose@8.0.1

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu, npm, mongoose

While installing node_modules, I use the `--legacy-peer-deps` or `--force` flags. This works fine on windows on my system locally, but it doesn't work while deploying the project in ubuntu server!

This is the error I get:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: @nestjs/mongoose@8.0.1
npm ERR! Found: mongoose@6.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/mongoose
npm ERR!   mongoose@"6.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   mongoose@"*" from @types/mongoose@5.11.96
npm ERR!   node_modules/@types/mongoose
npm ERR!     dev @types/mongoose@"5.11.96" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer mongoose@"^5.11.15 || ^5.12.4" from @nestjs/mongoose@8.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@nestjs/mongoose
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: mongoose@5.13.14
npm ERR! node_modules/mongoose
npm ERR!   peer mongoose@"^5.11.15 || ^5.12.4" from @nestjs/mongoose@8.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@nestjs/mongoose
npm ERR!     @nestjs/mongoose@"8.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-14T08_44_12_502Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Are you executing the same command locally and on the server? Are you sure the flags are interpreted correctly on Ubuntu?

Comment: idk, this is the first time I'm deploying on the server, and yes, I've studied that same command in the project directory will be working on ubuntu but not sure!

Answer (score 30):

It means you have dependency conflicts. So try running the following options one by one.

1. Remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and then run

   ```
   npm install
   ```
2. Or try clearing out npm cache

   ```
   npm cache clean --force
   ```
3. Or run the command with the `--legacy-peer-deps` option

   ```
   npm install --legacy-peer-deps
   ```
4. Or run the command with the `--force` option

   ```
   npm install --force
   ```

Comment: Plus one for `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: Plus one for `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

Answer (score 1):

This error can probably arise if you use yarn in your project and still try to run the `npm install` command. just try the `yarn` command instead. put here as an answer thinking it may be helpful for someone.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I haven't used yarn command, this was due to dependency issues on my project. Anyways, I just got my node_modules and solved the problem.