# Why can't Install packages into project?

Tags: reactjs, deployment, three.js, vite

Hi I'm new to react development and currently I'm following React Project Tutorial in Youtube.when after install vite into project I added this command into terminal

```
 npm install three @react-three/fiber @react-three/drei maath valtio react-color framer-motion
```

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: tshirt-builder@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @react-three/drei@undefined
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-three/drei
npm ERR!   @react-three/drei@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @react-three/drei@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @react-three/fiber@8.13.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-three/fiber
npm ERR!   peer @react-three/fiber@">=8.0" from @react-three/drei@9.78.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-three/drei
npm ERR!     @react-three/drei@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\yasit\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\yasit\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-13T10_50_32_761Z-debug-0.log
```

I need to know how i can fix this error...

Comment: [It means you have dependency conflicts.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72614890/16609157) your question may have been answered here.

Answer (score 0):

try this

1. --legacy-peer-deps: ignore all peerDependencies when installing, in the style of npm version 4 through version 6.
2. --strict-peer-deps: fail and abort the install process for any conflicting peerDependencies when encountered. By default, npm will only crash for peerDependencies conflicts caused by the direct dependencies of the root project.

```
npm install three --legacy-peer-deps
```

4. --force: will force npm to fetch remote resources even if a local copy exists on disk.